# Date is set to null when calling rest service

Tags: spring, rest, date, jersey-2.0

We have a rest

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("save")
public String save(PaycodeDTO dto)
```

We have a client

```
public void saveOrUpdateAndPushToMdm(PaycodeDTO paycode) {
    executePost("/services/paycode/save/", Entity.entity(paycode, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), String.class);
}


 protected <T, S> S executePost(String url, Entity<T> reqBody, Class<S> returnClass) {
     Response resp = executeRequest(getTarget()
                .path(url)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))
                .post(reqBody);
```

and the dto :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PaycodeDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean isDeleted;
    private Date validFrom;
    private Date validUntil;
```

with getters and setters.

We fill validFrom and validUntil before calling the rest, but then the call reaches rest validFrom is null, validUntil is null.

What is the problem ?

The rest uses jersey-spring3. version 2.22.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to register JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class